Website not responsive when published via GitHub Pages
The website link: https://theoneandonlycoderintheworld.github.io/aacproject/
On my code I have set 2 major breakpoints in CSS media query for portrait and landscape orientation. When I open on the live server it shows fine when I inspect and change the dimensions, I have then added the same file to the GitHub and viewed from its static website it does not show the landscape mode at all even I changed the dimensions, why is that?
Is the problem with the GitHub or in the media query orientation feature? You can see the full code by inspecting the website.
@media  (orientation: portrait){
        
    header{
        display: grid;
        position: fixed;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        height: 10vh;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.195);
        width: 100vw;
        font-family: "Poppins-Regular";
    }

    header div ul{
        display: none;
    }

    .portrait{
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: rgb(200, 198, 198);
        color: white;
        width: 100vw;
        font-size: 3vw;
        margin-top: 2.5vh;

        li{
            padding: 1vw;
        }

    } 

    .nav-bar{
        width: 5vw;
    }

    .logo-image{
        width: 15vw;
    }

    .header-box-navbar{
        justify-self: start;
        align-self: center;
    }
    .header-box-logo{
        justify-self: center;
        align-self: center;
    }

}


@media (orientation: landscape) {

        html{
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        header{
            font-family: "Poppins-Regular";
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            color: white;
            height: 10vw;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.311);
        }

        .nav-bar,.text-application{
            display: none;
        }

        .logo-image{
            width: 10vw;
        }

        li{
            display: inline;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .header-box-navbar,.landscape-applications,.header-box-logo{
            justify-self: center;
            align-self: center;
        }
    }

I tried to go and upload the code in w3schools website uploader in there also it works fine responsively.

Please edit your post to add some screenshots and/or illustrations. I am not clear on what your desired result is, compared to your actual result.

The page you linked is index.html, but the CSS you show in your question is that of aac-home-responsive-new.html. That page is responsive on my end :)
